crypto-js PBKDF2 1,000 times weaker than specified in 1993 and 1.3M times weaker than current standard
I have a question regarding this vulnerability. I'd like to know what this actually means. Is it just some fantasy of GitHub Dependabot, or it is really something dangerous?
If I use it to encrypt my crypto private keys, will someone be able to decrypt them (without knowing my password)? Could you please explain in a simple manner what this vulnerability is in reality?
import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';

export const encryptPrivateKey = (privateKey: string, password: string) => {
    const privateKeyBytes = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(privateKey);
    const key = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(password, CryptoJS.SHA256(password), { keySize: 256 / 32 });
    const ciphertext = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(privateKeyBytes, key, { mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB });

    return String(ciphertext);
};


export const decryptPrivateKey = (encodedKey: string, password: string) => {
    const key = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(password, CryptoJS.SHA256(password), { keySize: 256 / 32 });
    const decryptedBytes = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encodedKey, key, { mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB });
    const decryptedHex = decryptedBytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);

    if (decryptedHex[0] == decryptedHex[1] && +decryptedHex[0] == 0) {
        const decrypt = decryptedHex.substring(0, 1) + 'x' + decryptedHex.substring(2);
        return decrypt;
    }
    return decryptedHex;
};

Will you be able to get the raw private key from the its encrypted version?
sEf9jM/BCXfQ94758EMFGcru3jut3U2vKhcZlyqL7xTU+/eeBkoJsQoiKQ6XQm0i


In v4.2.0 the default values were changed, the iteration count from 1 to 250,000, the digest from SHA1 to SHA-256, see https://github.com/brix/crypto-js/commit/421dd538b2d34e7c24a5b72cc64dc2b9167db40a. Note that CryptoJS is no longer maintained, s. https://github.com/brix/crypto-js?tab=readme-ov-file#discontinued.

Yes, I understand that, it's just the person that I work with seem to not wanting to move from the 4.1.1 version and would like me to provide facts on practice that it is really dangerous to use............

So don't use the default SHA1 and 1 iteration.

The insecurity concerns the default values, both the iteration count and the digest can and could be set explicitly, e.g. CryptoJS.PBKDF2("Secret Passphrase", salt, {keySize: 256 / 32, iterations: 250000, hasher: CryptoJS.algo.SHA256})

thanks for the info. But it would still mean the same as updating the dep in every repo etc ( what the person that I work with doesn't want to do ). So on-practice-wise, could you show or explain how one could get the raw private key with this sha1 and 1 iteration??

The main problem is the iteration count of 1: The iteration count has the task of slowing down an attacker, the smaller it is, the more attacks per time unit are possible. The iteration count is therefore usually set as high as possible while maintaining acceptable performance (a few 100,000 is quite common nowadays). An iteration count of 1 is definitely too small and is a clear vulnerability. There are countless posts about this on the web and anyone who is not convinced by this must be aware of this vulnerability (and should not be surprised if they are hacked).

ok I will try finding a post now, and will say some feedback here, thanks a lot!

Note that SHA1 (although generally insecure) is not deemed insecure in the context of PBKDF2/HMAC, see here, (nevertheless, the change to SHA-256 makes sense, if only to push SHA1 out of the ecosystem).

well I've googled some articles.. but I didn't see anything practical, they all just say that 1 iteration will make an easier bruteforce.. I understand that I guess for the ethical reasons nobody provides the code etc, but could you just explain in word what it would mean. So I'm a malicios user, I have the functions and the ecrypted key.. I start the bruteforce attack. How long would it take to accomplish it? For example I have a public level top-end pc.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Programming questions belong on Stack Overflow, security questions belong on Security.

PBKDF2 uses a cryptographic hash function with HMAC in an iterated way with a salt.
In this case, it's using SHA-1, which is subject to collision attacks and should no longer be used, but we don't believe current attacks can be exploited in the context of PBKDF2.  (Note that, despite what some people say, HMAC-SHA-1 is not always necessarily secure; for example, using HMAC-SHA-1 as a commitment scheme is totally insecure.)
This version of CryptoJS also appears to have a default of 1 iteration, which has always been insecure.  In this construction, there is little more than a single invocation of HMAC-SHA-1, which is extremely cheap and most simple passwords can easily be cracked using password lists or variations on them with little effort.  Since part of the goal of using a password hash is to provide additional security for weak passwords, this is not considered an acceptable configuration.
In general, the preferred algorithms for modern password hashing, such as Argon2 and scrypt, are memory-hard, which means that they require a certain amount of memory to be used in computation to reduce parallelization on GPUs.  PBKDF2 is not such an algorithm, and using a newer, memory-hard function (e.g., Argon2id) is highly recommended.  If you need to target only FIPS algorithms, then PBKDF2 is your only choice, but you'll also generally need to use a FIPS-certified library, which CryptoJS is not.
If you absolutely must use PBKDF2, you should use it with a strong cryptographic hash function, such as SHA-256 or SHA-512, not SHA-1, and with a suitable number of iterations.  A number such as 250,000 is suitable on some machines now, but will need to be increased over time.
Also, if you're using cryptographic libraries, you should be using maintained ones, even more so than with regular libraries.  As the documentation mentions, most modern JavaScript environments provide cryptographic functionality, and it is better to use that when possible.  You could also use a secure Rust cryptographic library (such as the RustCrypto ones) to implement Argon2 and call into it via WASM, which would also probably perform better than doing the operation in JavaScript with CryptoJS.

The problem with (most) implementations of PBKDF2 is that they use SHA-1 or SHA-2 (e.g. SHA-256) as their hashing function.
That is no good. Hashing with any number of iterations of SHA-2 is not good for password hashing.
Even if you have 1,000, 10,000, 100,000, 250,000 rounds.
SHA is designed for data hashing; not password hashing
The SHA2 hashing algorithm is designed to be:

as fast as possible
require as little resources as possible

It's designed so it can be run on resource contrained devices—devices with very little RAM and very little CPU power. Devices like:

microcontrollers
routers
https web servers
embedded devices
credit cards

This means a single 2.5W USB stick can compute 330 million SHA-256 hashes per second. (And i own 17 of them.)
You need a password hashing algorithm
You need an algorithm that is designed to:

not be fast
not run on hardward constrained devices (e.g. a credit cards)
and to take as much advantage as of PC CPU resources as possible, e.g.:

L1, L2 caches larger than what an ASIC or GPU can affordably have per computation unit. E.g. GPU's have a Shared Memory (SM) size of 96 KB
complex instructions like ROL that CUDA doesn't support



Algorithms like:

scrypt — which is PBDKF2 using SHA-2, but uses an "expensive" function to compute the salt
bcrypt — which is stronger than scrypt for memory sizes under 16 MB
Pufferfish — which extends bcrypt from 4 KB to 128 KB (the size of your CPU L2 cache; and larger than than the 96 KB a GPU has as its shared memory (SM) pool)
Argon2 — which is memory hard, and great for key derivation, but weaker than bcrypt for password hashing

You should not be using:

MD5
SHA-1
SHA-2

Inclding wrapping them in PBKDF2 with any amount of iterations; because no amount of iterations can salvage the use of them for password hashing.
So now you see how bad the vulnerability is

Crypto-js PBKDF2 is 1,000 times weaker than originally specified in 1993, and at least 1,300,000 times weaker than current industry standard. This is because it both (1) defaults to SHA1, a cryptographic hash algorithm considered insecure since at least 2005 and (2) defaults to one single iteration, a 'strength' or 'difficulty' value specified at 1,000 when specified in 1993. PBKDF2 relies on iteration count as a countermeasure to preimage and collision attacks.


they are using PBKDF2 when they shouldn't be
they're using SHA-1 when they should't be
they're using 1 iteration when they should be

If true, it is a truely terrible implementation



Algorithm
Underlying hash function
Iterations
Secure




PBKDF2
SHA-1
1
❌


PBKDF2
SHA-1
2,000,000
❌


PBKDF2
SHA-512
1
❌


PBKDF2
SHA-512
2,000,000
❌



